# Fixed Points in the Von Neumann universe (updated)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Assume $V = HOD$, i.e. every set is hereditarily ordinal definable. Then, use this to fix some well-ordering $<_V$ on the von Neumann universe $V$. Define $V(\gamma)$ to be the order type of $V_\gamma$ with respect to the ordering $<_V$. Then, since $V(\gamma)$ should be normal, could we apply Veblen's theorem and find fixed points i.e. solutions to $V(\kappa) = \kappa$, for cardinals $\kappa$? If so, what would these fixed points look like? Note I am working with cardinals rather than ordinals, as ordinal solutions, assuming they exist, would likely be far more abundant than cardinal solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V(\gamma)$ need not be normal, and may not have any fixed points at all besides $0$, $1$, and $2$.  For instance, $\emptyset$ could be the greatest element with respect to $<_V$, and then $V(\gamma)$ will be a successor ordinal for all $\gamma>0$.  (Notice, for instance, that it will fail to be continuous at $\omega$ since $V(n)$ is finite for all $n<\omega$ but $V(\omega)$ will be an infinite successor ordinal.)  So, if $\gamma>0$ and $V(\gamma)=\gamma$ then $\gamma$ would have to be a successor ordinal, but if $\gamma>2$ is a successor ordinal then $|V_\gamma|>|\gamma|$.